# Why i get failure error in SQL Server dtexec?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm new to `sql server` and use the `dtexec` utility to run `ssis` package, but when using this command:

```
dtexec /f e:/package.dtsx
```

I get this error:

> Source: Data Flow Task Cleanup: 100% complete End Progress Warning: 2016-10-18 09:05:31.61 Code: 0x80019002 Source: Package
>   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The
>   Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2)
>   reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs
>   when the number of errors reaches the number specified in
>   MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. End
>   Warning DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>   Started: 9:05:31 AM Finished: 9:05:31 AM Elapsed: 0.219 seconds

This raises up the `ssis MaximumErrorCount` too 10, and get that error again!

How can i solve this problem? Thanks all.

Comment: are you able to run the package manually without dtexec? If not run the package in your development tool and identify the error from the particular task.

Comment: Where are the *other* errors? This message says that there are *other* errors that caused the package to fail.